# SandboxPostCopy and Organization.IsSandbox

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, sandboxpostcopy

Could you tell me what would be the value of IsSandbox if I specify the following class during sandbox creation? Will it be 'true' or 'fasle'?

```
global class HelloWorld implements SandboxPostCopy {
  global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
     Organization org = [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization];
     // if(org.IsSandbox) {} ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Dev II Exam question?

Comment: @C0DEPirate It does in fact return true. Had to run it myself just to check.

Comment: @martin You are right, I also just tested it.
*Deleted my comment*

Comment: @C0DEPirate You were right though. It does return true.

Comment: @C0DEPirate I refreshed a sandbox.

Comment: So can we say, this class is running after the sandbox is created, and hence returning the value as true?

Comment: @C0DEPirate that's what it looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The query will return `true` for `Organization.IsSandbox` when this code is run as part of a sandbox refresh.

I ran the following class:

```
global class SandboxRefreshClass implements SandboxPostCopy {
  global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {
      insert new Account(name = 'Context Org Id: ' + context.organizationId() + ' Context Sandbox Id: ' + context.sandboxId());
      insert new Account(name = ' UserInfo Session Id:  ' + UserInfo.getSessionId() + ' UserInfo Org Id:  ' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId());
      insert new Account(name = ' Organization IsSandbox: ' + [SELECT IsSandbox FROM Organization].IsSandbox);
    }
}
```

And got the following results:

> Context Org Id: `/* 15 digit sandbox org id */` Context Sandbox Id: `/* 15 digit sandbox id (07E not 00D)*/`
>
> UserInfo Session Id: `null` UserInfo Org Id: `/* 18 digit sandbox org id */`
>
> Organization IsSandbox: `true`

Comment: I see if my refresh script is dependent on UserInfo.getSessionId() I'm screwed.

Comment: @mardok Unfortunately that seems to be the case for now.